# Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation:error with modal form

Tags: javascript, html, servlets

this is my first question in stackoverflow, in my html page i have a table, i want to send data to the servlet using modal form. But, i have this error :Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation.

table.html

```
<body> 
 <table border="1">
 <tr>
 <th>ID</th>
 <th>NAME</th>
 <th>ACTION</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>1</td>
 <td>JHON</td>
 <td><input type="button" value="display" class="d"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>2</td>
 <td>Max</td>
 <td><input type="button" value="display" class="d"></td>
 </tr>
 </table>

<div id="dialog-form">    
    <input type="text" value="" id="id">   
    <input type="text" value="" id="name">  
    </div>
    <div id="res"></div>    

 </body>
```

test.js

```
$(".d").click(function(){       
var id =$("#id").attr("value",$(this).parent().prev().prev().text());
var name =$("#name").attr("value",$(this).parent().prev().text());   

$("#dialog-form").dialog({  
  modal: true,  
   buttons: {
    "Send":function () {

   $.post("Controller",{id:id,name:name},function(data){
   $("#res").html(data);

   }) ;
    }
```

Servlet.java

```
String name=request.getParameter("name");
String id=request.getParameter("id");
out.println(id +" "+ name);
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Where is the error occurring? Have you tried to use a debugger or any other research? See also [ask].

Comment: thanks, i think the error is in the js file, function Send

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are trying to modify the value and update it in the backend.

```
var id =$("#id").attr("value",$(this).parent().prev().prev().text());
var name =$("#name").attr("value",$(this).parent().prev().text());
```

This will assign the objects to the variables id and name. You cannot send them in ajax and you don't need to. Hence the error.

In your case, you need to update the modal text box with the id and name values and send them to the server. Also do note that since it is a text box, you need to send the updated value which the user might have changed.

Hence we do the following changes.

First we just set the id and name values in the text box present in the modal

```
$("#id").attr("value", $(this).parent().prev().prev().text());
$("#name").attr("value", $(this).parent().prev().text());
```

Then in the ajax post, we send the updated value taken from the text box

```
$.post("Controller", {
    id: $("#id").val(),
    name: $("#name").val()
}, function (data) {
    $("#res").html(data);
});
```

Here is the working code http://jsfiddle.net/xec61c0m/